# FormatAccountName exception after logging into Forms site

Tags: exception-handling, forms-authentication

I've started receiving the following Sharepoint exception whenever I log a user in via Forms Authentication;

> Value cannot be null.   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.FormatAccountName(String
>   provider, String user)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.FormatAccountName(String
>   user)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.CopyUserToken(SPUserToken
>   userToken)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SPSiteConstructor(SPFarm
>   farm, Guid applicationId, Guid
>   contentDatabaseId, Guid siteId,
>   SPUrlZone zone, Uri requestUri, String
>   serverRelativeUrl, Boolean
>   hostHeaderIsSiteName, Uri redirectUri,
>   Pairing pairing, SPUserToken
>   userToken)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm
>   farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean
>   contextSite, SPUserToken userToken)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm
>   farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean
>   contextSite)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.BaseApplication.Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PreRequestExecuteAppHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Can anyone please help me to determine why this is happening or how to prevent it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get some help from here:
http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/fixing-the-elusive-%E2%80%9Cvalue-cannot-be-null%E2%80%9D-fba-authentication-error/